# Robot Framework test work locally but not when executed with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I'm running a test suit with Robot framework which accesses a remote directory.

There is no problem when I run the test cases locally to access the remote machine, but when I use Jenkins to run the tests it tells me that it cannot find the remote directory.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using any jenkins slaves for execution ?

Comment: Try accessing same directory from jenkins executor with jenkins user manually

Comment: @Chandella07 yes I'm running it on a jenkins slave machine

Comment: If it’s telling you it can’t find a directory, it is telling the truth. Either you’ve misconfigured something or you need to create the directory. You haven’t given us enough details to help.

Comment: @BryanOakley  The directory exist and I can access it when executing the tests on my machine but not when I execute them from Jenkins

Comment: Please share the error logs. If you are on linux OS, check for the permission for the user which you have used in Jenkins for slave login, user might not have permission to the directory where your suite file exists.

Comment: Thank you Guys, I've found the origin of the problem : Jenkins server could not access remote files because network copy from the Jenkins server was not activated